# Is it possible perform actions in POCO before insert/update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let's assume this Entity Framework sample:

```
public class User
{ 
    public int UserID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }      
} 

public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
} 

class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        using (var db = new MyDbContext ()) 
        {     
            var user = new User { Name = "Foo"}; 
            db.Users.Add(user); 
            db.SaveChanges();      

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit..."); 
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I want add to **User** class events, like "BeforeInsert" or "BeforeUpdate", and when the code...

```
db.Users.Add(user);
```

... is executed anywhere in the application, the "BeforeInsert" method will be raised. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JC's answer is correct. I will just show code, in which you can do what you want. First of all, override SaveChanges method in your context, and call this overriden SaveChanges method: **context.SaveChanges(true)** instead of *conntext.SaveChanges()*

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 

    public int SaveChanges(bool performCustomOperations)
    {
        if(performCustomOperations)
        {
            CustomContextManager contextManager = new CustomContextManager(this);
            //Perform operations you want before saving data
            contextManager.PerformBeforeUpdate();

            //To do: Add your own PerformBeforeInsert method to CustomContextManager class
        }

        //Save changes to underlying database
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Your CustomContextManager class should look like this. Performing your before update operations in **PerformBeforeUpdate** method. You can add your own *PerformBeforeInsert and/or PerformBeforeDelete* methods.

```
public class CustomContextManager
{
    private MyDbContext context;

    public CustomContextManager(MyDbContext contextParam)
    {
        if (contextParam == null)
            throw new ArgumentNUllException(nameof(contextParam));

        this.context = contextParam;
    }

    public void PerformBeforeUpdate
    {
        //Get object context to be able to perform operations
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext myObjectContext =
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> updatedRecords =
            taxesObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

        if (updatedRecords != null
            && updatedRecords.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntry in updatedRecords)
            {
                if (stateEntry != null
                    && stateEntry.Entity != null)
                {
                    //Do what operations you want instead of below linnes
                    User modifiedUser = stateEntry.Entity as User;
                    if(modifiedUser != null)
                        modifiedUser.Name = "Altered before update";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do that in an override of the `SaveChanges()` method of your `DbContext`. Scan through the `ChangeTracker.Entries` collection for any entries of your type. Then for each of those, do your BeforeInsert or BeforeUpdate operations based on whether `entry.State` is `EntityState.Added` or `EntityState.Modified`.