# EF Core, Identity: How to track changes made to database?

Tags: entity-framework-core, identity, tracking

Using Identity, I am simply doing calls like
userManager.UpdateAsync(user); to make changes to the database.

But how do i track these changes, to put into my db "change" tables. I need a way to do it in the program itself, to include the ID of the user who made the change.

Any help?

Comment: I am not sure if it works for EF Core, but check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28576778/1380428) to similar question. It may help

Comment: As far as I know, Identity should also have context, but I am not sure